# ExpressionChanged Error occurs only when running a unit test after Angular update

Tags: angular, unit-testing, typescript, karma-runner

maybe someone could shed some light on the problem below.
We've updated to Angular 4.4.6 from Angular 4 a couple weeks ago. We faced some ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError exceptions here and there but finally fixed them. All of them were possible to track just by using the application at runtime. The problem is that for one component we only face this exception when interacting with that component from inside of our unit tests and everything works just fine when we use it at runtime. (dev build of course).
We use Jasmine + Karma to run our tests.

I did some investigation on this and found out experimentally that this exception occurs only when we clear the filter - basically calling clearFilter function. During this call we also try to set the focus on the input element of the filter - this is the root of the problem. If i remove this line `input.focus();` from **filter.component.ts** - everything just works. But i would really like to know if there is a way to achieve the same focus functionality without triggering an Angular's ExpressionChanged error? Please advice.

**filter.component.html**:

```
<div class="columns is-gapless" [class.no-match]="filterValue && !filteredItems?.length">
    <div class="column is-narrow is-centered">
        <i class="filter-icon material-icons md-18 ">filter_list</i>
    </div>
    <div class="column">
        <input type="text" placeholder="Filter" [ngModel]="filterValue"
         (ngModelChange)="updateFilter($event)" #input i18n-placeholder data-test-filter/>
    </div>
    <i *ngIf="filterValue" class="close material-icons md-16 is-clickable" (click)=clearFilter(input) data-test-close-filter>close</i>
</div>
```

**filter.component.ts:**

```
@Component({
    moduleId: "" + module.id,
    selector: 'filter',
    templateUrl: './filter.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./filter.component.scss']
})

export class FilterComponent {
    @Input() set items(items: any[] | Set<any>) {
        if (items instanceof Set) {
            this._items = Array.from(items);
        } else {
            this._items = items;
        }

        if (this.filterValue) {
            this.applyFilter();
        } else {
            this.filteredItems = this._items;
            this.itemsFiltered.next(this.filteredItems);
        }
    };
    @Input() set value(value: string) {
        this.filterValue = value;
        let valueUpper = value.toUpperCase();
        if (valueUpper != this.valueUpper) {
            let incremental = valueUpper.length > this.valueUpper.length && valueUpper.indexOf(this.valueUpper) != -1;
            this.valueUpper = valueUpper;
            this.applyFilter(incremental);
        }
    };
    @Input() set comparer(value: (item: any, filter: string) => boolean) {
        this._comparer = value;
        this.applyFilter();
    };

    @Output() itemsFiltered = new EventEmitter<any[]>();
    @Output() valueChange = new EventEmitter<string>();

    filterValue: string = "";

    private _items: any[];
    private _comparer: (item: any, filter: string) => boolean;
    private valueUpper: string = "";
    filteredItems: any[];

    clearFilter(input: HTMLInputElement) {
        input.focus();
        this.updateFilter("");
    }

    updateFilter(value: string) {
        this.value = value;
        this.valueChange.next(value);
    }

    private applyFilter(incremental = false) {
        if (!this.valueUpper || !this._comparer) {
            this.filteredItems = this._items;
        } else if (!incremental) {
            this.filteredItems = this._items && this._items.filter(this.checkFilter, this);
        } else if (this.filteredItems) {
            this.filteredItems = this.filteredItems.filter(this.checkFilter, this);
        }

        this.itemsFiltered.next(this.filteredItems);
    }

    private checkFilter(i: any) {
        return this._comparer(i, this.valueUpper);
    }
}
```